# mysql database table corruption

Tags: mysql, restore

Today when I opened MySQL database and I couldn't see very important table which were present/created about couple months ago. Yesterday I worked on it.

Do you have some suggestions, how to get my table back?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Impossible to answer without more information

Answer (score 1):

Power failure?  MyISAM engine?  Then REPAIR TABLE.

Going forward, recommend converting to InnoDB; it is more resilient to power failures.